# Creating resource only DLL with translated form resources

Tags: delphi, dll, resources, localization, delphi-6

I have a large application which i want to migrate to Arabic. I have defined the strings that we show to the user under the resourcestring keyword.

I am using the External Translation manager provided with Delphi 6. However, I am not very much comfortable using the tool. I want to create a resource only dll with all the translated strings like how the Delphi ETM does, and then switch between languages at run-time at the click of a button.

I was able to link the resourcestrings to the Dll, but how about form's captions and hints and the component properties? I am loading the Dll at runtime depending on the language, but the form properties are not reflecting as they were not available in the Dll.

Any pointers in the right direction ???

Thanks 
Rahul W

Comment: Are you using Delphi 6 and if so, doesn't Arabic require Unicode? Another alternative if you haven't seen it is [gnugexttext for Delphi](http://dxgettext.po.dk/)

Comment: @Mike: Arabic doesn't need Unicode, as long you're running on a system set to the Arabic ANSI codepage and proper font support is available. What Unicode allows for is mixing several different languages in the same application. Non Western languages were supported by computer long before Unicode was designed.

Answer (score 1):

What the Delphi localization tool and runtime support do is to redirect resource loading - including forms - from the executable to the DLL. Forms, their components and controls (non default properties) are stored as resources into the executable (as long as you don't create them fully at runtime - but then you would have to set their properties one by one).

Thereby if you want to work alike the standard translation tool you have to work the same way. What the DLL Resource Wizard does is to extract all project .dfm (and those you add manually) and resourcestrings to a copy that can be localized. When an app is started the form loading code checks from where the .dfm should be loaded. You should override this code to load your resources.

Be aware that changes language at runtime may need a different approach, because loading a whole form from resources may "reset" it to the creation state. On the other hand, compared to approaches like gettext, it allows to localize far more than the form text, including images, colors, and to adapt control sizes to the new string easily. IMHO gettext is good for simple needs, but when localization becomes a complex task and you may need to localize for a very different "culture", more powerful tools are needed.

Comment: +1. Text content is only one part of the localization. And even for the text only, given that languages verbosity can greatly vary, you often need to adapt design to accommodate for it (not even going into layout depending on Text Direction)

Comment: @Idsandon I tried to figure out from the delphi code in Classes, System.pas files, but i wasn't able to find a routine which is loading the form from the resource. I tried putting breakpoints in the code, but few breakpoints were not enabled. If you know of any routine which will load the components from resource, then it would be of great help to me...

Comment: Moreover, one thing that still surprises me is the ability to add the translations at run-time instead of re-compiling the exes. I have checked the source of gnugexttext, the idea is to use the language files embedded within the exe or can be saved on the file system, but will this not slow down the application performance, like, checking every time whether the component has translation or not? Correct me if i am wrong... I want to develop a framework.